# Проблема с картинками в python&kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Вставил png картинку, заранее убрав задний фон.
Но при запуске задний фон белый.
Нужно убрать его.

```
BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, .7
            Player:
                id: player
                allow_strerch: False
                size_hint:None,None
                canvas:
                    Rectangle:  
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        source:'hero.png'
                width: '25dp'
                height: '25dp'
                x: root.width/20
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы пробовали через Image картинку добавлять?

Comment: нет, сейчас попробую.